# How can I use pancakeswap router to charge tax on sell and buy

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I am quite new to solidity, and I just created my first bep20 token.
However, I am trying to implement a sell and buy tax using pancakeswap v2 router but I haven't been able to figure out how to implement this as the pancakeswap documentation is weak when it comes to being beginner-friendly.

Please I'd appreciate any help with this, and possibly how I can test it on testnet.

Comment: I am not really sure abotu what you want to implement as a tax. But I would change the _transfer() function to write the tax here and take the tax from here to put it in the wallet of your choice. 

I am not 100% sure how that would work with pancake swap though

Comment: [You can find more details on buy and sell tax in this article](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/programming/token-tax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pancakeswap router only handles trades, it does not handle taxes and other special functionality.

As mentioned in the comments, you have to implement such custom functionality in `transfer` and `transferFrom` functions. So, for example, if user wants to transfer 100 tokens to account B, your transfer functionality takes 100 from the sender, assings 99 to the receiver and keeps 1 as tax.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity @Lauri.
But, if I may ask, how can one know when a user is selling the token or buying it?